# Is it possible to embed an Electron app and a data's file in a single executable?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-forge

I want develop a simple desktop app and a option is use Electron, but a requisite of my project is that have a single executable file, I can do it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-builder, but I have a `.json` file too, to store my data, so, I can embed all these files in a unique file (executable with database) ?

I can do it using Java Swing and embedded SQLite on a unique `.jar` file, but I want know if I can do it on Electron too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You only need to config `build`, `target` and `platform` in `package.json` file. For example

```
"build": {
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "portable"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": "AppImage"
    },
```